# Angular http.post header issue

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, post, drupal-7

**How do I send CSRF and Token data in a http request?**

I'm using Angular to post json data to a Drupal services endpoint but I'm experiencing problems.

```
//  drupal post node
$scope.post_node = function(){
            console.info('Node post ...');

            var promise = $http.post('http://mysite/QuestionsGenerator/angularjs-headless/api/v1/node', 
                {
                    "title" : "Node Test",
                    "body" : "Node body contents test#2",
                    "type" : "page"
                }, 
                {
                    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRF-Token' : $cookieStore.get('user_session_token'),
                    'Cookie' : $cookieStore.get('user_session_cookie')
                }
            )
            .then(
                //            successCallback,
                function(response){
                    console.log('Post-node working ...');
                    $log.info(response);
                },
                //            errorCallback
                function(response){
                    console.log('Post-node NOT working ...');
                    $log.error(response);
                }
            );

            return promise;   
        }

    }]);
```

Using the code above, I'm trying to post to a Drupal services endpoint for a node to be created - so I have to post a *title*, *body* and *node type* for the new node.

In addition, I have to post **X-CSRF-Token** and **Cookie** information which authenticates my Angular user with Drupal so the node can be successfully created.

However, I receive the following error: `Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"` followed by a message which says the user is not logged in - I can confirm the user not only exist but is logged in.

My network tab shows no details of my token or cookie details begin sent - which would explain the user not begin authenticated.

How can I send my cookie and token data?

**UPDATE**

I tried adding the *withcredentials* line as in the code below:

```
var headlessQS = angular.module('headlessQS', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

headlessQS.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
    $routeProvider

      $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/wiris', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/wiris.html',
        controller: 'wirisController'
    })

    .when('/signin', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/signin.html',
        controller: 'signinController'
    })
});

// Controllers

......
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=headlessQS&p1=…
```

Also, when the withcredentials code does work, do I add my token etc data like in the following code:

```
var promise = $http.post('http://mysite/QuestionsGenerator/angularjs-headless/api/v1/node', 
    {
        "title" : "Node Test",
        "body" : "Node body contents test#2",
        "type" : "page"
    }, 
    {    
        headers: {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-Token' : $cookieStore.get('user_session_token'),
            'Cookie' : $cookieStore.get('user_session_cookie')
        }
    }
)
.then(
    //            successCallback
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `$cookies`, and you set:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true; // from main module
```

then your cookies should be sent on every request.

By default, `$http` will also read a token from an `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie and apply an `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header to the request.

If you're trying to send a JWT token as a Bearer token on the Authorization header, look into using an HTTP Interceptor:

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {
      var access_token = tokenService.getAccessToken();
            if (access_token) {
                if (config.url.indexOf(this.myAPIUrl) === 0) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
                }
            }
      return config;
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Note: You can also use the HTTP Interceptor to capture all HTTP responses, and errors on HTTP requests and responses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben. Please pardon my newbness but I've no idea where or how to integrate your suggestions into my code. Believe me, I've tried and not succeeded, so far. Can you offer my direction, please?

Comment: You should be able to implement the `$httpProvider` defaults with a `.config` block in your main AngularJS file (most likely app.js).

Comment: I tried that approach without success. I added an update to the original question for you to see what I mean. Thanks for your ongoing help